# Can I forget all my UIKit and Core Animation knowledge when I decide to do everything in OpenGL ES?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, core-animation

I was reading that OpenGL ES can work together with Core Animation. So I wonder if I can re-use some of my hard-worked knowledge on Core Animation when I start doing OpenGL ES stuff...

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty much on your own when you decide to use OpenGL. The only thing you're going to use your EAGLView for is to get the touch events.

Now the Quartz stuff is still useful - to draw 2d graphics at runtime and display them in your OpenGL code as textures. But Core Animation isn't useful at all.

EDIT: To expand on that slightly, you can use Core Animation and the UIView methods to do all the normal stuff to an EAGLView, but you shouldn't, the EAGLView should not have any UIViews overlaping it either. Both will kill performance.

Comment: While overlaying a translucent CAEAGLLayer on top of other UI elements is guaranteed to kill performance, if the OpenGL layer is opaque I don't believe that you lose that much by overlaying UIViews and other elements on top of it.  I've benchmarked both with and without UIView overlays and not seen that huge of a difference in performance.

Comment: Agree, if you are not using some complex engine with UI support, it is easier to have UILabels and other stuff over GL View and it doesn't hurt performance much, at least if area is small enough.